# For Loop Values Repeating and Sum

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, for-loop, codeblocks

I have never asked for help in a forum before and will typically research the heck out of a problem, but this is my first programming class and this week I lost 3 family members and am extremely behind where I'd like to be for the week. Any help would be appreciated, but I'm hoping someone can write this using different variables. ((caveat: I know how to write in the prompt to request the user's name)) For example, numbers 20-50, display the number entered 44 times adding 82 to the number each time. I feel like this is cheating, but if someone could provide the example, at least I have to put in the appropriate numbers requested by the instructor. Thanks in advance and if ya think this is asking too much, I understand.

Create IPO Chart, Pseudocode, Example Output after Execution:
Prompt the user to enter their name and prompt the user to enter a number from 1-10. Then write a FOR loop to display the number entered 25 times adding 10 to the number each time.

Comment: Does this have to use javascript or PHP?

Comment: PHP I believe, but the instructor didn't specify

Comment: The appropriate response, in your case, is to ask for compassionate consideration from your academic supervisor, rather than ask for a solution here (which may be against the academic policy of your school or university). Please also see [this post about adding "urgent" to a request"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326569/under-what-circumstances-may-i-add-urgent-or-other-similar-phrases-to-my-quest)

Comment: If it's wrong to ask for an example, my apologies. I've never asked for help like this before. Suppose I won't do it again either. Getting compassionate consideration will still put me behind, which I'm trying to avoid. Might be unavoidable. ((I just want to do graphic design and could pull my hair out for having to learn this stuff too -- eek!!))

Comment: It's not wrong to ask for an example, but asking for a complete solution to a homework problem is [off-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). Please also remember that if a complete solution is posted as an answer you won't be able to delete your question and then the academic supervisor will be able to find your code by searching here. If you want an examples of for loops,[w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_looping_for.asp) is a good place to start. Then if you have any questions or doubts, you can try posting a specific question here.

Comment: I've been to w3. I'm utterly confused as this is my FIRST time attempting programming. It's not for everyone. I was going to rephrase my question, but honestly, I don't even know how to re-write it. So, nm. Just giving up for now. I'm out of energy.

Comment: Start by reading the link to w3schools I posted in the previous comment, then apply that to your problem. What is your `init counter', what is your 'test counter', what is your 'increment'?

Comment: The question does specify the language very clearly. 'Pseudocode'. In other words, write down, in plain language but hinting at normal code structures, how you'd code it. Doesn't ask for a working solution. (Unless there's more to the question that you've posted.)

Comment: You need to look at your instructor's examples of pseudocode. Usually `for` loops have an "init counter" (starting number), "test counter" (end number) and "increment" (how much you add each time).

Comment: Thank you for attempting to help / teach me. I was able to get help from a friend who was able to break it down for me Barney-style. The way this stuff seems to me is that people who already know it, for the most part, teach it like this:

Me: What is an Apple?
Them: An apple is an apple.
Me: Ok (still confused) Thank you for trying.

Comment: @DavidRawson After having the barney-style session, your last comment makes a ton more sense. Thank you again for your efforts to teach a dumdum like me. :)

Comment: You're not dumb. I'm glad you could get someone to help with your problem. Good luck with your studies